# Get current system time of a machine on the network

Tags: python, time, networking, system

I understand that I can query system time of my machine like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now()
```

Is there a way to query the system time of another machine on the windows network? 
Eg of `\\mynetworkpc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

on a Windows machine there is `net time \\<remote-ip address>` to get the time of a remote machine but I don't know if it is portable.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(r"net time \\172.21.5.135")
Current time at \\172.21.5.135 is 10/18/2010 12:32 PM

The command completed successfully.

0
>>>
```

Comment: this works for me. In addition to ip address, you could also use the machine name, both work fine.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a Python WMI module with the answers to this question: [get-remote-pcs-date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836816/get-remote-pcs-date-time)