# DateTime from Remote PC on LAN

Tags: c#

For my application needs, I would like to get current DateTime from server PC connected with LAN. After googled, I found an [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28VS.85%29.aspx). But it is written in vb. How can i do it in c#? Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Try these to convert http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ or http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836816/get-remote-pcs-date-time). It's perfectly working for me.

```
try
{
string pc = "pcname";
//string domain = "yourdomain";
//ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
//connection.Username = some username;
//connection.Password = somepassword;
//connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + domain;

string wmipath = string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", pc);
//ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(
//    string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", pc), connection);
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(wmipath);
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Win32_LocalTime instance");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}-{1}-{2}", queryObj["Year"], queryObj["Month"], queryObj["Day"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}:{1}:{2}", queryObj["Hour"], queryObj["Minute"], queryObj["Second"]);
}
}
catch (ManagementException err)
{
Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + err.Message);
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedErr)
{
Console.WriteLine("Connection error (user name or password might be incorrect): " + unauthorizedErr.Message);
}
```