# Wonderware System Platform. How to get DateTime from remote PC?

Tags: .net, scripting, wonderware

How can I recieve system time from remote PC in local network within InTouch Scriptng or QuickScript.NET in Archestra IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve any of the answers here : [Get remote PC's date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2836816/804773)

**QuickScript.NET Example**

First, Import the `System.Management` DLL from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` or wherever you have it located as a Script Function Library.

After that, use this script and tweak to your needs:

(I had this in an ArchestrA graphic with 2 text fields, `datestring` and `timestring` were tags tied to the display objects.

Script Condition: While `refresh` == True  :

```
dim pcname as System.String;
dim wmipath as System.String;
dim scope as System.Management.ManagementScope;
dim query as System.Management.ObjectQuery;
dim search as System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher;

try
    pcname = "192.168.10.190";

    wmipath = System.String.Format("\\{0}\root\CIMV2", pcname);
    scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(wmipath);
    query = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime");

    scope.Connect();
    search = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    dim queryObj as System.Management.ManagementObject;
    for each queryObj in search.Get()
        datestring = System.String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", queryObj("Year"), queryObj("Month"), queryObj("Day"));
        timestring = System.String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", queryObj("Hour"), queryObj("Minute"), queryObj("Second"));

        LogMessage(datestring + " " + timestring);
    next;
catch
    LogError(error);
endtry;

refresh = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually my .net version is 3.5 so "try  catch" is not supported. But, anyway, I'll try to use your advice without "try catch"

Comment: Yeah that's rough without the try-catch but as long as you can do something to handle cases where it fails. I had received a permission issue running the code once on my VM but I think they had a solution in the linked answers to that situation.