# Getting the current time for a domain in the same network I am connected to

Tags: c#, networking

I am connected to a network, but not joined to a domain (in the same network), I still can access some of the allowed resources in the domain. If I am connected to this domain then the time will be automatically set but this way it is not. Is there a way to get the current time in the domain which is available in the same network I am connected to? I know the domain's name.

Comment: do you have domain login credentials accessible for your program?

Comment: Maybe if the DomainController(or gateway/router/) computer has [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) service running, then using the NTP service.

Comment: @pasty is correct. That would be the best way. An SO question has answered the NTP situation  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c

Comment: @bwtrent I have a valid login credentials for that domain..

Comment: Are you trying to do the same thing as `net.exe time /DOMAIN:otherdomain` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt u got it right!

Answer (score 1):

There have been numerous SO questions on how to get another server's time. You need to find out what NTP server they are syncing against and query that server. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008111/get-the-exact-time-for-a-remote-server) should get you to where you can update your time. The domain should have their ntp.domain.com open for that network but you can not be sure on what their systems engineer/administrator decided to do.

Also, most networks that are smaller simply sync against a known good public NTP server.