# How to sync system clock with global date/time?

Tags: c#, process, synchronization, system-clock

My system clock is going crazy randomly at any moment and changing the system clock's date/time to a random one. It's not the lithium battery nor a virus because I checked. Also it's not something from the `Windows.System.Time` itself.

I want to create a process that will, on an interval, check to see if the system clock's date/time matches the global date/time and if not, it would sync.

I need this to run in the background. I am not even sure if a Windows process is correct way to accomplish this. I am open to any other solutions as well.

Comment: You could create a windows service to do this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A Windows GUI app is a process too. When you run Notepad, you run a process. What exactly do you mean. You need to spell it out.

Comment: Sorry David, I just edited the question. Thanks for the quick reply. Anything else should I know ?

Comment: I guess you are looking to write a Windows service. However, don't write a service to sync time. The system can already do it and it is surprisingly hard to do well. Very likely your code will get it wrong.

Comment: So you say the better option is Windows service and also in the same time not to write a service just to sync time.
If you are right, then, what do I write ?

Comment: Well, there seems to me to be little point in writing a service to perform a function that the OS already does better than you can

Comment: The reason I am doing this is the system's clock is going crazy randomly at any moment (i.e. changing the date and time to a random one). And no, it's not the lithium battery nor a virus because I checked those. Also it's not something from the Windows.Time itself. It's Weird and I need to find a solution. Thanks for your previous answer, David.

Comment: You simply need to update your question with your clarifications, not the comments.  You should delete the comment.  I'll update your question.

Comment: I think it much more important to find out **why** your system clock is “going crazy”.

Comment: Your question has been updated and it is should now be ***much more clear*** as to what you are wanting.  However, this still might not enough because at this point you are simply asking for a solution.  You need to try to do this yourself and then edit your question adding in the code that you've tried if it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new c# empty project. Click on the project and go to Properties change the output type to Windows Application (This will remove the console).

Create a new class example: Example.cs

Write the static entry point eg:

```
public class Example
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Insert your code in the Main routine.

This will create a process that contains no console/window/service.

I'm guessing this is what you want.

Comment: Yes It's as simple as I want. Thanks.
And by the way, do you know how can I fetch current time from a server ? You don't have to type a lot. Just give me articles or links to read.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008111/get-the-exact-time-for-a-remote-server