# Get date and time from server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a website based on MVC and I am using **DateTime.Now** for time operations like countdowns. But sometimes there can be a difference between users' devices and the server. For example:

> Device time: 12/4/2019 4:22:46 PM
>
> Server time: 12/4/2019 4:22:38 PM

And this time difference is a huge problem for me. I've searched and couldn't find anything about it, but is there any way to get server's date and time?

PS: This can be done via javascript or jQuery, either.

Comment: Related? [Get the exact time for a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1008111/1364007)

Comment: @WaiHaLee I can't open a port, so it doesn't work for me. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use on the server side the DateTime.Now function and pass to the web page by inserting it into ViewData["Time"] and when you load the web page compare it with
the javascript Date.Now() function on page load.